# log4net - want a .net 4.0 version

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, log4net

I love log4net, but am frustrated that there is no VS2010/.NET 4.0 version of it.
So, decided that I will just grab is from SVN and have my own version of it.

Can someone please convince me that there is a better way to go?  I like what it does and how it works, and heck I would contribute back a new solution myself if I understood how Apache contributions worked.

Comment: Doesn't the version targeted at .NET 2.0 work for you?

Comment: Yes, the .net 2.0 version does indeed work as a plain dll, and that is what we've been doing for a long while now.  But if and when I want to reference the source code in a project, or even alter something, I need to create my own VS2010 version if I'm in a VS2010 project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a better way to go. We use the log4net from NuGet in our .Net 4 solution, without any issues.

I believe log4net depends on the `System.Web` DLL, which is not included in the .Net 4 client profile. If you must use the client profile, and log4net, you'll have to compile your own. [This](http://gosheg.blogspot.com/2011/04/log4net-in-net-40-c-applications-net.html) post may be  a good start.

Comment: Me, too. Would be curious to hear what the poster's complaints are. I can't imagine of any .NET 4 features being helpful in LOG4NET.

Comment: There is nothing new in 4.0 that is needed in log4net as far as I know.

Answer (score 2):

We just reference the log4net.dll in all our projects and that is no problem at all. There is no problem using a dll compiled for .NET 2.0 under .NET 4.

Comment: Older versions of log4net required the full .NET profile because they had a dependency on System.Web.

Answer (score 2):

Support for the client profiles of .NET 3.5 and 4.0 was added in [log4net v.1.2.11](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/release-notes.html). The dependency on System.Web was removed.